# echo out values from a php object

Tags: php, object

I have a php object called `$result`　(got from `json_decode`), below is a print_r of the object. I'm trying to echo the question number and answer. ex:

```
4 answer1
5 answer2
```

How do i go about doing this.

```
stdClass Object
    (
    [request] => stdClass Object        (
            [other] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [4] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [answer] => answer1
                        )
                    [5] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [answer] => answer2
                        )
                )
        )
    )
```

I'm still learning OOP. As a simple approch i tried `echo $result->request->other->4->answer` to echo the first answer, but that doesn't seem to be right. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Man what an RTFM question - Did you try - how about reading http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.array.php or even http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Comment: @AdrianCornish The real problem of this question is `how to get the value of the number property of an object`, your two links doesn't help much.

Comment: So the question is wrong and of extremely low quality because the OP does not know what they are doing or want. This can never help someone else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap the number property with `{}`:

```
echo $result->request->other->{4}->answer;
```

Comment: @AdrianCornish Yes, this is the direct answer to this question. What do you mean by `adding a method to the class`? to which class? Image this is the result of a result of `json_decode`.

Comment: @AdrianCornish That's just an example, the point is stdClass is not created by you.

Comment: @AdrianCornish He is close, the only problem is the property name is number. How could you say `unspecified call`? And could you tell the way you will do to access the value of `answer` ?

Comment: @xdazz, yes this is json decoded. Thanks, Your answer works. I will just need to loop thru it. Much appreciated.

Comment: @AdrianCornish This is not lucky guess, almost `90%` if you know php. You are missing the point that even if you wrap the response object to give it some method, you still need to access the original object.

Comment: @AdrianCornish I'm sorry this is not still clear. You know that `stdClass` doesn't have methods, don't you?

Comment: @AdrianCornish Hi, Adrian, `stdClass` is php built-in class, you can't have your own class called stdClass. php's `json_decode` returns `stdClass` object if you don't set the second parameter to true. You could get Array too if you want.

Comment: @AdrianCornish Check http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.classes.php

Comment: @xdazz - You are correct - did not know that - just found http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.classes.php - I think I should probably delete all my comments

Comment: @AdrianCornish Never mind. PHP just has something different compared to  the language you familiar with :)

Comment: @xdazz So true - I used to be - but it moved on when I was not looking - thanks for correcting me and teaching me something new - Removing my `wrong` comments